# Numerical integration and plotting

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

New to Mathematica, and trying to numerically evaluate two integrals:

```
  g[x_] := (x + 1) Log[x + 1] - x Log[x];
  C = NIntegrate[g[1/(Exp[1/x] - 1)], {x, 0, a}];
  P = NIntegrate[1/(x (Exp[1/x] - 1)), {x, 0, a}];
```

and plot `C` as a function `P`, if possible. Kindly help.

Comment: C is defined by Mathematica, look in the documentation. This works points=Table[{c=NIntegrate[g[1/(Exp[1/x]-1)], {x,0,a}], p=NIntegrate[1/(x (Exp[1/x]-1)), {x,0,a}]}, {a,0,1,.01}];
ListPlot[points, Joined->True] but gives some errors that you might be able to figure out. Otherwise NIntegrate demands every variable have been given some value first.

Comment: By saying “plot C as a function P”, do you mean you want to use `P` as the independent variable of `C`?

Answer (score 2):

According to your definition we have

```
g[x_] := (x + 1) Log[x + 1] - x Log[x]
```

The two functions performing the numerical integration are

```
fC[a_] := NIntegrate[g[1/(Exp[1/x] - 1)], {x, 0, a}]
fP[a_] := NIntegrate[1/(x/(Exp[1/x] - 1)), {x, 0, a}]
```

Remarks

1) variable names must begin with a lower case letter, hence I have written fC and fP instead of C and P, respectively.
2) delayed assignment (:=) is requested and the upper integration limit must appear as an argument of the function.

Now you could plot both functions, for instance like this

```
Plot[{fC[a], fP[a]}, {a, 0, 5}]
(* picture not shown here *)
```

Comment: I think you mistyped the definition of `fP`?

Comment: @xzczd: Yes, I did. Thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected it.

Comment: The OP wants to plot `fC` as a function `fP`, maybe like `ParametricPlot[{fC[a],fP[a]},{a,0,5}]`?

Comment: Yes, ParametricPlot.The resulting curve is almost a straigt line.